In Berlin, Germany, does any rental-price limit apply to fixed-term rental contracts?
A few laws are currently in place in Berlin Germany to limit the maximum monthly price for rental contracts. One such law is the Mietpreisbremse. However it does not always apply: one of the exceptions is related to fixed-term contracts.
On the internet I found several incompatible interpretations of such exception.

I read it might depend on the contract's duration: interpretations vary between contracts of "any length" / "up to one year" / "up to six months".
I also read it might depend on the reason for the contract's time-limit: an interpretation is that this does not matter, while another is that only contracts limited because of a need of the tenant are excluded.

In which cases does the Mietpreisbremse, or other similar laws, apply to fixed-term rental contracts? I am interested both to the relevant parts of the law as well as court decisions on the matter.

I think the restrictions come from being fixed-term. In order to use a fix-term contract the apartment needs to be furnished. In this setting the Mietpreisbremse does not apply.

This was covered on TV and the channel was a state owned one.  They had their lawyer on there explaining many things.  Wie So had this as well.  Best answer is to take that term contract to the RAT House and the department concerning rent prices.  They can advise you to get a lawyer or not and have several on file that handle things like this.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
